# How to create a customhook in reactJS which when clicked browser back button pops a confirm box.and on cancel stay on same page?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

This is my current progress. But i am not able to make it work.Even if the history is changing internally within the buttons of my application.still it is getting trigerred.can anybody help me??

```
import {  useEffect,useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory,useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';



export const useGoBack = ()=>{
  
   const history =  useHistory();
   const location = useLocation(); 
   

    useEffect(()=>{
       
         const unlisten=(event)=>{          
            
             history.listen((location, action) => {                            
                if(action === 'POP');
                {  
                                         
                    let result = window.confirm("Are you sure u want to leave?");
                    if(!result)
                    {
                       history.goForward();
                    }
                   
                }
            });
         }
        window.addEventListener('popstate',unlisten);
        return () => {window.removeEventListener('popstate',unlisten)};
       
     
    },[location.pathname]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define any dependency in useEffect, an empty array will be enough, also I recommend you to use window.addEventListener("popstate", unlisten) or history.listen(), not both:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const unlisten = (event) => {
      console.log(event);
      //...
    };
    window.addEventListener("popstate", unlisten);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("popstate", unlisten);
    };
  }, []);
```

or:

```
  useEffect(() => {
     return history.listen((location) => {//...}
  }, []);
```